# Google sites CSS nav bar 'pushing' text?

Tags: css, navigation, navbar, google-sites

I'm working on a css and html navigation menu on google sites but I can't seem to be able to 'rollover' my menu and have the sub menus show *over* the text that I have underneath? [This is the link to the site](https://sites.google.com/site/yetanothertest234/) and this is the css bit of the code I'm using for it but I really don't know how to go about this.

```css
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
#primary_nav_wrap
{
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;  
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
list-style: none;
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0; 
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul a
{
 display:block;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:32px;
 padding:0 15px;
 font-family:"HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li
{
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item
{
 background:#ddd
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover
{
 background:#f6f6f6
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
 background:#fff;
 padding:0
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul li
{
 float:none;
 width:200px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul a
{
 line-height:120%;
 padding:10px 15px
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul
{
 top:0;
 left:100%
}

#primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul
{
 display:block
}
</style>
```

I've been copying and pasting mostly for css and then trial and error but i would like to be able to copy and paste this in every single one of my pages (in the google sites html box gadget) and just treat it as a fixed menu bar - is that possible?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your CSS here

```
#primary_nav_wrap ul
{
  list-style: none;
  width: 500px;
  /* height: 500px; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

Commenting out the line I have above seems to fix the problem of the nav bar pushing your text aside.